# Fade in and fade out text at the same location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a code which can toggle two sentences fading in and fading out. But I want to toggle the sentences at the same location ie one text fades and the other starts coming in place of the first. In this case the sentences occur one below the other. Is there any way I can do this as in html content always comes one below the other.

This is the jquery script.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(function(){
       $("#hide1").hide();
       while(1)
      {
       $("#hide2").fadeOut(3000);
       $("#hide1").fadeIn(3000);
       $("#hide1").fadeOut(3000);
       $("#hide2").fadeIn(3000);
     }
 });
});
</script>
```

Html

```
<p id="hide1"> Hide 1 <p>
<p id="hide2"> Hide 2 <p>
```

Comment: can you please share jsfiddle ?

Comment: 'Is there any way I can do this as in html content always comes one below the other.' is this what you want or it should replace the place of previous text?

Comment: try absolute position in styles.

<p id="hide1" style="position:absolute"> Hide 1 <p>

<p id="hide2" style="position:absolute"> Hide 2 <p>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wdLsT/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9U6qh/2/)**
Try like this  make the queue and animate

```
  $("#hide1").hide();

function hide1() {
    $("#hide2").fadeIn(3000);
    $("#hide2").fadeOut(3000, hide2);
}

function hide2() {

    $("#hide1").fadeIn(3000);
    $("#hide1").fadeOut(3000, hide1);
}
hide1();
```

OR  Chaining

```
$("#hide1").hide();

function hide1() {
    $("#hide2").fadeIn(3000).fadeOut(3000, hide2);
}

function hide2() {
    $("#hide1").fadeIn(3000).fadeOut(3000, hide1);
}
hide1();
```

---

This code would react dynamically, and it does not need any changes even if you want to apply this effect for more than two p elements

```
$("p").hide();

function test(elem) {
    elem.fadeIn(1000, function () {
        elem.fadeOut(1000, function () {
            test(elem.next('p').length ? elem.next('p') : $('p:first'));
        });
    });
}

test($('p:first'));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RYa37/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('#hide1').fadeOut(1000, function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.text($this.text() == 'Hide 2' ? 'Hide 1' : 'Hide 2');
        $this.fadeIn(1000);
    });
}, 3000);
```

Toggle the text within the `setInterval` function.

## Fiddle Demo

Answer (score 1):

Use a single paragraph tag and toggle the text within it while you try to fade it in and out.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
        window.setInterval(function() {
            $("#hideorshow").fadeToggle(1000, "linear", function() {
                $("#hideorshow").text($("#hideorshow").text() === "Hide 1" ? "Hide 2" : "Hide 1");
                $("#hideorshow").fadeToggle(1000, "linear");
            });            
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Also, I would suggest you use `fadeToggle()` instead of `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`.

Here is a working [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RYa37//).